# Solr grouping only if there are more than group

Tags: php, solr

I am trying to group result in solr by condition.
If the result contain may more than 1 group, then do grouping, show 4 products per group. If there is only one category, then show all products in that category.

How to do this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

After my research:

There is no way to check group number before hand. So we have to make 2 request.

- First request: a request with group parameterget group number and if it's greater than 1 then return data, no need to make the second request. But if it have only one group, continue with second request
- Second request: a search quest **without** grouping parameter. Get all product and return data.